# Why Qt Creator doesn't allow to add new files and classes to project if I selected CMake build system ?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

[image]

As you can see the button "Добавить новый" ("Add new"), Добавить существующие файлы ("Add existing files")... are disabled. When I create new project and select build system qmake - these button are enabled always.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons are disabled since Creator can not programmatically edit CMakeLists.txt files. CMake files are just too complex to have an IDE change them in a reliable fashion. To do that you would need to enforce that projects agree on a common layout for their buildsystem files and to file best practices, which is just not an option for an IDE like creator.

You can still manually edit this files and add your sources in the right places.